# sum convergence in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

for $s>0$, I need to show that $\sum \frac{f(n x)}{n^s}$  converges for integrable $f$.

So far I can show that $\frac{f(n x)}{n^s}$ is integrable for $s>0$.

I tried to show this using partial sums but it is not guaranteed by the givens.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a change of variables $y=nx$. Then
$$\int f(nx)dx = {1\over n}\int f(y)dy$$
and the sum becomes
$$\sum {1\over n^s} \int f(nx)dx = \left(\sum {1\over n^{1+s}}\right) \int f(y)dy.$$
So it is converging.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum\left|\frac{f(nx)}{n^{s}}\right|dx=\sum\frac{1}{n^{s}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(nx)|dx=\sum\frac{1}{n^{s}}\frac{1}{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|dx=\sum\frac{1}{n^{s+1}}\|f\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})}<\infty,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\sum\left|\frac{f(nx)}{n^{s}}\right|<\infty
\end{align*}
for almost everywhere $x\in\mathbb{R}$.